# hostgator smtp email to gmail with symfony swiftmailer does not get received

Tags: php, symfony, email, smtp, gmail

i'm trying to send email with standard symfony framework version 2.5.*
and swiftmailer. 
for testing puposes i'm using just the console command

```
php app/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

i've tried configuring swiftmailer with hostgator email settings 
SMTP ssl and non ssl(same result)

everything works fine if i send email to my domain address 
for example from `test@domain.com` to `test2@domain.com`

but if i send email to my gmail account there is nothing in my inbox 
example from `test@domain` to `myacc@gmail.com`

what maybe the cause of this? 
gmail is blocking my emails or what?

Comment: Yes, gmail is blocking your mail. Check the gmail documentation on how to get mail accepted. Don't forget to do that for all big mail receivers, like live.com yahoo.com and so on.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255